# I cloned my windows ssd and set target ssd as 1st boot priority, but there is no option to load second windows

Tags: windows, ssd, cloning, copy

How can I fix it? I used "macrium reflect" to clone.
Do I need to perform some extra steps now? Why it is not working?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question.  Do you want both drives to be accessible and bootable or is it that the one you cloned won't boot on its own.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I was expecting both to be bootable. Do I need to disconnect source ssd to let target ssd load? Do I need to plug target ssd in the same sata port? And how do I make them both bottable at the same time? Is there any tools for it?